# Window top scroll not corresponding

Tags: jquery

I want to know when I scroll to the bottom of the page so I did this

```
docH = $(document).height();
winH = $(window).height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == docH - winH){
        console.log('bottom reached');
    }
})
```

But when I scroll to the bottom nothing happens but I copied and pasted it on another page and it worked fine.

So I did this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log(docH);
    console.log(winH);
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
})
```

So I realized that when I scroll to the bottom I get this values

```
docH = 29028
winH = 717
```

Now by calculation the window.scrollTop should be docH - winH which is 28311 but I get this value 28311.111357894

Please do anyone knows the cause of the decimal and how I can fix it?

Comment: you can use `parseInt(docH - winH, 10) ` to convert floating point number to integer

Comment: I would also suggest not using `==` for comparison, instead do something like `$(window).scrollTop() >= (docH - winH - 1)` to avoid potential rounding issues.